# Access service into static method in Angular 5

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to access the service's reference into my static method like so :

```
export class myComponent {
  constructor(private backend: BackendService) { }

  public static myMethod() {
  myComponent.backend.getData()
    .subscribe(
      data => { console.log(data)   },
      error => { console.error(error); }
  );
 }
}
```

I'm getting `Property backend doesn't exist on type 'typeof myComponent'`

How can I access `backend` reference?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to do this, probably looks like bad architecture but you can achieve this by doing the below.

```
 export class myComponent {
  constructor(private backend: BackendService) {
     this.constructor.backendService = backend;
  }

  public static myMethod() {
   myComponent.backendService.getData()
     .subscribe(
       data => { console.log(data)   },
       error => { console.error(error); }
   );
  }
}
```

This will work only when the static method is called after component's initialization.

Answer (score 0):

First and best solution : Just DON'T use a static method to consume your service.

Another one if you really want to make harder simple things ;)

```
@NgModule....
export class AppModule
{

    constructor(public injector: Injector)
    {
        myComponent.injector = injector;
    }
}
```

Then in your static method;

```
var myService = myComponent.injector.get(BackendService);
myService.getData(....);
```

Answer (score 0):

As of **Angular 14** you can use the **inject function** to do this. But you need to take care that, the function is called within a valid context.

```
export class myComponent {
  public static myMethod() {
    inject(BackendService).getData().subscribe(
      data => { console.log(data)   },
      error => { console.error(error); }
  );
 }
}
```

Valid context:

- Construction (via the constructor) of a class being instantiated by the DI system, such as an @Injectable or @Component.
- In the initializer for fields of such classes.
- In the factory function specified for useFactory of a Provider or an @Injectable.
- In the factory function specified for an InjectionToken.

(Source: https://angular.io/api/core/inject)

Comment: But we can't use inject out of construction context, so this will throw an error. have a look 
NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `EnvironmentInjector#runInContext`. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0203

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem as well. I have used @Injectable class instead static method. Maybe it can help you too.

```
  @Injectable
  export class myComponent {
  constructor(private backend: BackendService) { }

  public myMethod() {
  myComponent.backend.getData()
    .subscribe(
      data => { console.log(data)   },
      error => { console.error(error); }
  );
 }
}
```