# Inject a service into a static method in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngxs

I have implemented a logger service. I use NGXS for state management and the selectors in NGXS are static methods. I am now unable to use the logger service, that I injected via Angular DI, in the static selectors.

Is there a clean and nice way to use the service in the selectors?

```
constructor(
  public logger: LoggerService
) {}

@Selector()
@ImmutableSelector()
public static get(state: StateModel) {
  // <-- Log via LoggerService
  return state.model;
}
```

Comment: That method is intended to be used as nothing but a selector. If you want only logging you can try something like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngxs-custom-logger?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts)

Answer (score 2):

> First of all, don't use a static method to consume your service. It is not a good practice.

Anyway if you want to use it.

> Just import your service in the constructor and then you can use

```
export class myComponent {
  constructor(private logger: LoggerService) {
     this.constructor.logService = logger;
  }

  public static myMethod() {
   myComponent.logService.log_method()
     .subscribe(
       data => { console.log(data)   },
       error => { console.error(error); }
   );
  }
}
```

here it is answered here already. [Access service into a static method in Angular 5.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47790383/access-service-into-static-method-in-angular-5)
Do a little more search

Comment: I know this is not good practice, is there a better way to solve the problem?

Comment: No sorry, I don't